# Grouping and counting across 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble totaling combing the count and group by functions in MySQL.

There are two tables I need to produce a summary report from. The relevant tables:columns are:
Students: ID,FirstName,LastName,SchoolID
Schools: ID,ShortName,FullName,Group,HeadCoachID

Each School is assigned to a **Group** in the database where three or four schools will share a Group number. I need to count the number of students in each group of schools.
I can count the number of students in each school and sort the schools by Group. From there I can just use Excel to sum the number of students in each group. But I should be able generate the report directly from MySQL.

```
 SELECT Schools.Group,Schools.ID,Schools.ShortName,Count(Students.ID) From
 Students LEFT JOIN Schools on Students.SchoolID=Schools.ID 
 GROUP BY SchoolID ORDER BY Schools.Group
```

The output of this command is something like this:

```
Group   ID  ShortName   Count(Students.ID)
 2     137  NSHA HS             21
 2     117  Great Neck North    32
 2     118  Great Neck South    30
 3     120  HANC                13
 3     114  Freeport            23
 3     126  Kellenberg          10
 3     152  Uniondale           18
```

What I want to produce is this instead:

```
Group   Count(Students.ID)
 2       83
 3       64
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just wanting the `SUM` of the counts for each `Group`.  Since you already have the results you're looking for, you can put that in an inner query, and group/sum those results:

```
SELECT  `Group`, SUM(`Count`)
FROM
(
    SELECT      Schools.Group, Schools.ID, Schools.ShortName, Count(Students.ID) As `Count` 
    From        Students 
    LEFT JOIN   Schools on Students.SchoolID=Schools.ID 
    GROUP BY    SchoolID 
) As X
GROUP BY `Group`
ORDER BY `Group`
```

Though, the inner query is just a copy/paste from yours - I'm wondering how it's working at all.  There isn't anything listed as `SchoolID` in your `Select`.  But it should point you in the right direction nonetheless.

Perhaps this is more what you are looking for?  As `ShortName` is never used:

```
SELECT  `Group`, SUM(`Count`)
FROM
(
    SELECT      Schools.Group, Schools.ID, Count(Students.ID) As `Count` 
    From        Students 
    LEFT JOIN   Schools on Students.SchoolID=Schools.ID 
    GROUP BY    Schools.Group, Schools.ID 
) As X
GROUP BY `Group`
ORDER BY `Group`
```

Or, possibly even without an inner select, and just directly:

```
SELECT      Schools.Group, Count(Students.ID) As `Count` 
From        Students 
LEFT JOIN   Schools on Students.SchoolID = Schools.ID 
GROUP BY    Schools.Group
ORDER BY    Schools.Group
```

These should give some idea where to go.

Comment: Thank you! I understand inner queries better now. Just grouping by `Schools.GROUP` worked fine too.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Schools.Group, Count(Students.ID)
  From Students
  LEFT JOIN Schools
    on Students.SchoolID = Schools.ID
 GROUP BY Schools.Group
 ORDER BY Schools.Group
```

You need to group by schools.group if you want one row per group, not students.schoolid (what you are currently grouping by). Also you have ID and Shortname in your SELECT list, but don't seem to actually want those columns selected, based on your desired output.

Note that you might get one row where schools.group is blank, and a count representing whatever schools on the students table don't have a match with the schools table. If you don't get such a row, then the outer join is pointless and you should use an inner join rather than a left outer join.